# Graphics object cannot reference the nonstatic field method or property

Tags: c#, winforms

The non-static field, method, or property, "Form1.pic", cannot be referenced by a field initializer, in this case I am guessing are the "private Graphics gfx". While pic can be successfully referenced throughout the code, it can't be properly referenced as a variable in the public partial class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.Util;
using Emgu.CV.OCR;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;

namespace Acatek_Text_Extractor_Project
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        private Tesseract OCRz = new Tesseract("tessdata", "eng", Tesseract.OcrEngineMode.OEM_TESSERACT_ONLY);
        private Bitmap pic = new Bitmap(481, 300);
// All of the code in this line below is correct except for "pic" being underlined for the supposed error. 
        private Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(pic);
        

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            gfx.CopyFromScreen(new Point(this.Location.X + PictureBox.Location.X + 4, this.Location.Y + PictureBox.Location.Y + 30), new Point(0, 0), pic.Size);
            PictureBox.Image = pic;
        }

        private void ExtractButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OCRz.Recognize(new Image<Bgr, byte>(pic));
            ResultBox.Text = OCRz.GetText;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just leave the `gfx` definition where it is, but instantiate it in the constructor:

```
private Graphics gfx;
```

And then in the constructor:

```
gfx = Graphics.FromImage(pic);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why should we *extract* `Graphics gfx` as a *field* at all?

1. We use it in just *one* place (we have nothing to *share* between methods)
2. It's *easy* and *cheap* to create (we have nothing to *cache*)
3. Finally, we *have to* `Dispose` it

Something like this:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //DONE: we should Dispose Graphics to realease HDC unmanaged resource 
    using (Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(pic))
    {
        gfx.CopyFromScreen(new Point(Location.X + PictureBox.Location.X + 4,
                                     Location.Y + PictureBox.Location.Y + 30), 
                           new Point(0, 0), 
                           pic.Size);

        PictureBox.Image = pic;
    } 
}
```